# How can I host a blazor web assembly SPA on a razor page

Tags: c#, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I can create a .net 7.0 web hosted blazor web assembly application, which creates the client and the server projects, but the blazor assembly is still hosted on a static html page.

I can also create a multi page razor pages application with single blazor component on each page.

How do I create a multipage razor pages application and have a multi page blazor SPA contained on a single cshtml page, please?

Given there may be routing problems, is this even possible?

Comment: your requirement sounds complicated to have blazor inside razor - why not write them in either razor or blazor? but i digress. the dumbest way though, embed the blazor using `iframe`.

Comment: Thanks, Bagus.
The reason: I have many razor web apps, but would like to convert the components they all have in common, into a blazor SPA and share it amongst them.
This will make future development much quicker.
However, I still need the razor page they run on to be rendered on the server, which an html page isn't.

Comment: Is this document helpful to you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly

Comment: Thanks, Tiny. This method hands over ALL routing to the razor pages, effectively allowing one component per page.

Comment: Okay, I've decided to use a DynamicComponent and load the different blazor pages using the web assembly code.
The skill set is not unlike ajax loading partials.
It might be slightly better, because the initial loading of the whole blazor web assembly could take a while.